# escape double quotes inside double quotes

Tags: bash, shell

i am trying to run below command inside a grovvy script, how ever i am getting below error:

please help

```
illegal string body character after dollar sign;
solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}" @ line 10, column 192.
mage-deprecation --image-id "{}" --depre
```

```
sh "aws ec2 describe-images --filters Name=name,Values=${params.KUBE_AMI_NAME} | jq -r '.Images[].ImageId' | xargs -0 -I aws ec2 enable-image-deprecation --image-id "{}" --deprecate-at $(date -d +10days)"
```

Comment: Just remove them here.

Comment: The quotes around `{}` aren't necessary. But quotes around `$(date -d +10days)` probably *are*, given the default output format of `date`.